# Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'STRING'

Tags: swift3, swifty-json

This was working in Swift2 but now in Swift3 (after automatic conversion) I'm getting an error:

`if self.entry["scheduler"] || self.entry["owner"]`

`Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'STRING'`

The values of self.entry["scheduler"] etc. are boolean but I think the issue is the indices, "scheduler" and "owner"

Of course, I reference other indices of `self.entry` in the exact same way and get no error when I build.

xcode auto updated and I am living in a nightmare.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Substitute whatever type you're expecting for the `.string` in the first two lines

```
let scheduler = self.entry["scheduler"].string
let owner = self.entry["owner"].string

if(scheduler != nil || owner != nil)
{
    // Take care here - scheduler and owner are both optionals
}
```

Comment: Additionally you can use a library like SwiftyJSON to solve this in more generic way. It provides you facility to case data to int, bool and other data types as well. 

`responseBody["driver_profile"]["name"].stringValue` , responseBody["driver"]["age"].intValue 
For more details, https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON
Furthermore those methods depend on your Swift and Package versions.